# What type of applications need to merge multiple heaps?

Tags: data-structures, heap

Out of different available heap operations, I understand that decreasekey is needed to demote a job, increasekey is needed to promote a job and that removekey is needed to cancel/abort a job. What type of applications need to merge two or more heaps? Is there any real use case of heap merging?

Comment: What kind of heap are you talking about? Be much more specific.

Comment: This type of question is off-topic: very broad & opinion-soliciting, and not a programming question,. StackOverflow is not for such discussions (it's not a discussion forum).

Comment: @OndrejTucny - type of heap is irrelevant. "Is there any real use case?" - that's all opinion/discussion. "What type of applications?" - very broad, lots of potential responses. This just isn't a fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Generally, yes; however, the OP can get a chance to improve his question by making it more specific, don't you think? However, agree with the close vote.

Comment: @OndrejTucny TBH, not any specific heap but in general. I think there must be important use case for heap merging which is why binomial heap like complex data structures are invented. However I could not find any such use case in google search. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that I've actually used heap merging for.

I have multiple very large files that contain key counts. That is, each line contains a `[key, count]` pair. All keys are unique. I need a single heap that contains the top X (which can be very large) items from each file.

One way of doing this is:

```
create empty master heap
for each file
    use standard heap selection to get top 10 items from file
    add each item from file heap to master heap
```

Another way is to replace the loop that adds items to the master heap with a merge. Depending on what type of heap you use, the merge operation can be *much* faster. Pairing heap (and others) will do a merge in O(1).